# Symfony2 InvalidArgumentExeption

Tags: symfony

I am a new developer on Symfony plateform.
That's error on my site. How do I solve it?

**I am using file upload on form submit Then the error was coming but I have deleted all code but the error not gone.**

**Config.yml**

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

jms_security_extra:
    # Whether you want to secure all services (true), or only secure specific
    # services (false); see also below
    secure_all_services: false

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    translator:      ~
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ FOSCommentBundle ,WebmuchTrademarkBundle]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Webmuch\UserBundle\Entity\User

    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true

twig:
    form:
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
        # resources: ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig']

gregwar_captcha: 
    quality:          100
    distortion:       false
    height:           50
    width:            120
    reload:           true
    as_url:           true
    interpolation:    true
    background_color: [255, 255, 255]

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

sonata_admin:
    title:      ApplyMyMark Admin
    title_logo: newdesign/images/modifiedtrademarklogo310x86.png


    assets:
        stylesheets:

            # Defaults:
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/AdminLTE/css/AdminLTE.css
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/select2/select2.css
            - bundles/user/sonata//vendor/select2/select2-bootstrap.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/css/styles.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/css/layout.css
        javascripts:

            # Defaults:
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/jquery/jquery.form.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/jquery/jquery.confirmExit.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js
            - bundles/user/sonata/vendor/select2/select2.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/App.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/Admin.js 

imports:
    - { resource: @WebmuchTrademarkBundle/Resources/config/admin.xml }

knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template

fos_comment:
    db_driver: orm
    class:
        model:
            comment: Webmuch\TrademarkBundle\Entity\Comment
            thread: Webmuch\TrademarkBundle\Entity\Thread

assetic:
    bundles: [ "FOSCommentBundle" ]

ewz_search:
    analyzer: Zend\Search\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\TextNum\CaseInsensitive
    path:     %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/%kernel.environment%/lucene/index

k_phoen_sms_sender:
    pool:         memory    # can be null (and is by default)
    providers:    [nexmo]

    nexmo:
        api_key:     lala
        api_secret:  lala

fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: ckeditor # other choices are tinymce or simple, and form
            fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yoursel
            connector:
                debug: false # defaults to false
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                    uploads:
                        showhidden: false # defaults to false
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 2M


trsteel_ckeditor:
    class: Trsteel\CkeditorBundle\Form\Type\CkeditorType
    transformers: ['html_purifier']
    toolbar: ['document', 'clipboard', 'editing', '/', 'basicstyles', 'paragraph', 'links', '/', 'insert', 'styles', 'tools']
    toolbar_groups:
        document: ['Source','-','Save','-','Templates']
        clipboard: ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo']
        editing: ['Find','Replace','-','SelectAll']
        basicstyles: ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','RemoveFormat']
        paragraph: ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','-','JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock']
        links: ['Link','Unlink','Anchor']
        insert: ['Image','Table','HorizontalRule']
        styles: ['Styles','Format']
        tools: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']
    ui_color: '#dadada'
    startup_outline_blocks: true
    width: 1015 #Integer or %
    height: 400 #Integer or %
    language: 'en-au'
    filebrowser_upload_url:
        url: relative-url.php?type=file
    filebrowser_image_upload_url:
        url: relative-url.php?type=image
    filebrowser_browse_url:
        route: 
        route_parameters:
            type: image
    filebrowser_image_browse_url:
        route: elfinder
        route_parameters:
            type: image

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
            timestampable: false # not needed: listeners are not enabled by default
            sluggable:     true


services:
    bulksms:
        class: Webmuch\TrademarkBundle\Service\BulkSms
        arguments: ['no','msg']

    mailer_service:
        class: Webmuch\TrademarkBundle\Service\MailService
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "dev-master",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "@stable",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "~2.0",
    "Trsteel/ckeditor-bundle": "dev-master",
    "tilleuls/ckeditor-sonata-media-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "excelwebzone/zend-search": "dev-master",
    "excelwebzone/search-bundle": "dev-master",
    "kphoen/sms-sender-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "mlpz/mailchimp-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
    }
}
```

}

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with
> message 'Unable to load class "Sonata\BlockBundle\Models\BaseBlock"'
> in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\trademarkclick\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassCollectionLoader.php:259
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\trademarkclick\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassCollectionLoader.php(98):
> Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassCollectionLoader::getOrderedClasses(Array)
>
> ## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\trademarkclick\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2519): Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassCollectionLoader::load(Array,
>
> 'C:/xampp/htdocs...', 'classes', true, false, '.php') #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\trademarkclick\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2355):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->doLoadClassCache('classes',
> '.php') #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\trademarkclick\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2389):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\trademarkclick\web\app.php(28):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Requ
> in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\trademarkclick\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassCollectionLoader.php
> on line 259

Comment: How about some code?

Comment: Please post your composer.json, you're config.yml and explain when you get this error

Comment: I am using file upload on form submit Then the error was coming but I have deleted all code but the error not gone.

Comment: Please post you composer.json and your config.yml file

Comment: @ Mattia  I have posted both file.

Comment: Can you also add you AppKernel.php ? Thanks

Comment: @Mattia Yes But I have remove all my previous code.But problem was not solve

Comment: Yes but i can't see the AppKernel.php